# System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection doesn't contain a definiton for "MapHttpRoute" - VS 2012, Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012

I've just installed Visual Studio 2012 and started checking out MVC 4 and Web Api.
I've created a new MVC 4 app with Web API. Based on some examples and tutorials I started configuring my routes with:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "Controller only",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
            );
```

However, that results in an error that `RouteCollection` doesn't contain a definition for `MapHttpRoute`. Am I missing some DLLs installed? 
As far as I could see I have all the right DLLs and version installed.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I have solved it by adding a reference to `System.Web.Http` in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: I had add this reference . but still have error , please help to review [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908970/assembly-reference-missing-when-migration-asp-net-mvc4-from-beta-to-4)

Comment: @Joe.wang, did you add using System.Web.Http in RouteConfig.cs?

Comment: OMG...doh!...Need `using System.Web.Http`

Comment: Thanks for answer. Please also note that you should MapHttpRoute before you MapRoute for your regular controllers.

Answer (score 32):

Try referencing: 
System.Web.Http and 
System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll

Then add a using statement for namespace: 
System.Web.Http

Note: It could also be that your intellisense is acting up. In which case just go ahead and type your code manually and build.

Hope that helps

Comment: Adding System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll fixed my problem.

Comment: Intellisense was acting up for me.

Comment: In order to have System.Web.Http available in the references list, I first needed to apply the 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core' package to my project via the NuGet package manager.

Answer (score 5):

Just adding using `System.Web.Mvc;` solved my problem

Comment: This was the issue for me. I had a list of methods like MapHttpRoute and MapOwinRoute but I just wanted MapRoute, which was absent. Thanks!