# Assembly reference missing when migration Asp.net MVC4 from beta to 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I was working on a migration job from Asp.net MVC4 beta to Asp.net MVC4, But I had a problem of dll reference missing. please help me .

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = System.Web.Http.RouteParameter.Optional }
            );


            routes.MapRoute(
               name: "Default",
               url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
           );
        }
```

Above the code can't be compiled successfully, and Visual studio said `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpRoute' and no extension method 'MapHttpRoute' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

More important thing is this kind of problem often happened.Because the version of the Asp.net MVC change so frequently in these days. and So did the version of Windows Azure Client ApI. It is very annoying problem.I hope someone can give some advise of How to deal with it. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved it by adding a reference to System.Web.Http in RouteConfig.cs.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same problem but was unable to fix it by adding a reference to System.Web.Http.  I still received the same error: `System.Web.Routing.RouteCollection' does not contain a definition for 'MapHttpRoute'`.

I believe this is occurring because in the latest version of MVC4, MapHttpRoute is no longer supported.

As it turned out, the function `MapRoute` is identical in parameter construction.  If you replace `MapHttpRoute` with `MapRoute`, you should be able to compile your code and move onwards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding a reference to `System.Web.Mvc.Html` and `System.Web.Mvc` in the `web.config`.

```
  <system.web>
    ...
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
        <pages>
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    ...
  </system.web>
```